# docker-py: client and server don't have same version (client : 1.16, server: 1.15)")

Tags: python, centos, docker

docker-py 0.7.0 gives me the following error against a local Docker installation of Docker 1.3.2
and docker-py 0.7.0. The host ist running CentOS 6.6. How can this be fixed?

```
xxxx@dev1 myproject]$ bin/python d.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d.py", line 3, in <module>
    c.create_container(image='zopyx/xmldirector-plone')
  File "/home/xxxx/sandboxes/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 546, in create_container
    return self.create_container_from_config(config, name)
  File "/home/xxxx/sandboxes/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 554, in create_container_from_config
    return self._result(res, True)
  File "/home/xxxx/sandboxes/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 98, in _result
    self._raise_for_status(response)
  File "/home/xxxx/sandboxes/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 94, in _raise_for_status
    raise errors.APIError(e, response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 404 Client Error: Not Found ("client and server don't have same version (client : 1.16, server: 1.15)")

>>docker --version
Docker version 1.3.2, build 39fa2fa/1.3.2


>>docker version
Client version: 1.3.2
Client API version: 1.15
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 39fa2fa/1.3.2
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.3.2
Server API version: 1.15
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): 39fa2fa/1.3.2
```

Answer (score 2):

got the same problem yesterday. Force install docker-py=0.6.0. If you already have 0.7.0 installed, you need to clear your pip cache, otherwise pip will install 0.7.0 from your cache.

Cheers,
W

Answer (score 2):

**Solution if the client version is newer than the server version:**

Say you want to connect to your docker service like this:

```
docker_client = Client(base_url='tcp://127.0.0.1:2376')
# Alternatively:
# docker_client = Client(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
```

If the client version is newer than the server version, this leads to an error message like this:

```
docker.errors.NotFound: 404 Client Error:
Not Found ("client and server don't have same version (client : 1.22, server: 1.18)")
```

You can solve the problem by setting the `version property` of the docker.Client object (as @sredni suggested). Given the error above, you need to change the line to:

```
docker_client = Client(base_url='tcp://127.0.0.1:2376', version='1.18')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug docker-py is trying to use latest avaliable docker api. If you have latest docker everything is ok, if not you just need to pass 'version' into Client.

https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/0.7.0/docs/api.md